# Could not determine the dependencies of task

Tags: android

```
Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug.
```

> In order to use Instant Run with this device running API 17, you must install platform 17 in your SDK

how do I resolve this error?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by restarting the IntelliJ IDEA, adb server and reconnecting my smartphone to adb.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to Android Studio -> Preferences(MacOS)/Settings(Windows) -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Platforms.
2. Tick `Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean)`.
3. Press Apply.